# Android: Obtener Uri de una archivo mp3 extraido del dispositivo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

1. Desde trato de obtener la posicion me saca de la app  Con el
   siguiente codigo obtengo todas las canciones del almacenamiento del
   dispositivo
2. val songCursor: Cursor? =
   applicationContext.contentResolver.query(songUri, projection, null,
   null, null)

   ```
    if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (songCursor.moveToNext()){
        val songalbum:Int = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)
        val songtitle:Int = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
        val songpath:Int = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)
        val songartist:Int = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
        var Album:String = songCursor.getString(songalbum)
        var Titulo:String = songCursor.getString(songtitle)
        var Path:String = songCursor.getString(songpath)
        var Artista:String = songCursor.getString(songartist)
        Log.e("path: "+Path,"Album: "+Album)
        canciones.add(Canciones(Titulo,Artista,Path,Album))
             }
       }    //songCursor!!.close()
       return canciones 
        }
   ```

   Este metodo es el onBind del recycler desde donde mando los datos al
   acivity

   ```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
           var item = canciones[position]
           holder.Titulo.text = item.Titulo

           holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
               var intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, CancionActivity::class.java).apply {
                   putExtra("NombreCancion", item.Titulo).putExtra("Posicion",position)
               }
               context.startActivity(intent)
               // holder.bind(item, context)
           }
       }
   ```

   Y este metodo es el que uso para obtener la posicion y los datos de
   la cancion en otro acivity la linea canciones es la del error

   ```
           private fun getIntentMethod() {
           var intent: Intent = getIntent()
           Posicion = intent.getIntExtra("Posicion",-1)
           PlayPausa = findViewById(R.id.play)


           PlayPausa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa)

           var canciones: Canciones = ListSong.get(Posicion)


          }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la uri es asi:

```
 val audioProjection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)

val audioQuery = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val audioCursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(audioQueryUri, audioProjection, null, null, null)

 if (audioCursor != null && audioCursor.count > 0) {
                    if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        val idColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
                        val dateAddedColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED)
                        val titleColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE)
                        val displayName = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val artists = audioCursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
                        val size = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE)
                        do {
                            val id = audioCursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    
                            val dateAdded = audioCursor.getString(dateAddedColumn)
                            val name = audioCursor.getString(titleColumn)
                            val nameWithFormat = audioCursor.getString(displayName)
                            val artistName = audioCursor.getString(artists)
                            val sizeSpace = audioCursor.getLong(size)
                            val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(audioQueryUri,id)

                            val cancion = Canciones(....)

                            canciones.add(cancion)


                        } while (audioCursor.moveToNext())
                    }
                    audioCursor.close()
                }
```

Esto obtiene todas las musicas en tu dispositivo.

Y para obtener la duracion aqui le pasas la uri(es una consulta a los metadatos del archivo).

```
 private fun getDuration(uri: Uri): Long {
        val retriever =  MediaMetadataRetriever()
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        val time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)
        val timeMilliSec = time.toLong()
        retriever.release()
        //milliSeg  1000 = 1 seg
        return timeMilliSec
    }
```